# Sandboxing a node.js script written by a user running on the server

Tags: linux, node.js, security, docker, sandbox

I'm developing a platform where users can create their own "widgets", widgets are basically js snippets ( in the future there will be html and css too ).

The problem is they must run even when the user is not on the website, so basically my service will have to schedule those user scripts to run every now and then.

I'm trying to figure out which would be the best way to "sandbox" that script, one of the first ideas i had was to run on it's own process inside of a Docker, so let's say the user manages to somehow get into the shell it would be a virtual machine and hopefully he would be locked inside.

I'm not a Docker specialist so i'm not even sure if that makes sense, anyway that would yield another problem which is spinning hundreds of dockers to run 1 simple javascript snippet.

Is there any "secure" way of doing this? Perhaps running the script on an empty scope and somehow removing access to the "require" method?

Another requirement would be to kill the script if it times out.

EDIT:
 - Found this relevant [stackexchange link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107850/docker-as-a-sandbox-for-untrusted-code)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with docker, you would create a docker image with their script in it and the run the image which creates a container for the script to run in.

You could even make it super easy and create a common image, based on the official node.js docker image, and pass in the users custom files at run time, run them, save the output, and then you are done. This approach is good because there is only one image to maintain, and it keeps the setup simple.

The best way to pass in the data would be to create a volume mount on the container, and mount the users directory into the container at the same spot everytime.

For example, let's say you had a host with a directory structure like this.

```
/users/
     aaron/
     bob/
     chris/
```

Then when you run the containers you just need to change the volume mount.

```
docker run -v /users/aaron:/user/ myimagename/myimage
docker run -v /users/bob:/user/ myimagename/myimage
```

I'm not sure what the output would be, but you could write it to /user/output inside the container and the output would be stored in the users output directory.

As far as timeouts, you could write a simple script that looks at docker ps and if it is running for longer then the limit, docker stop the container.

Because everything is run in a container, you can run many at a time and they are isolated from each other and the host.

Comment: Would you raise any settings i should really pay attention? 
For instance let's say the user gets the shell from node.js, how could i be sure he won't "get out of the docker" and "own" my host machine?

Comment: There are no known security exploits where a user can break out of a container with an up to date kernel and the latest docker version . As long as you keep docker and your kernel updated, any known exploits would be quickly fixed, as this would be a big problem for a lot of people.

Comment: the user would just upload a javascript and run on a node process..

so i guess i can somehow remove access to "system methods" so he hopefully won't touch the file system or buffer overflow something?

Comment: If you want, you can lock down the container even more. Have it run as a special user in the container, that is locked down, and you could even use a shell like rbash (restricted bash) to limit access even more. I would even go one step further and run in an alpine image, with only the bare stuff installed, so there isn't much they can do, due to the limited install base. You could even change the PATH, to only have a subset of binary directories, and alias any commands you might not want them to run.